# How can I reduce the length of this code?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I've manage to develop an automation script for my Samsung package updates but the length of it bothers me. It works fine when I run it but I think shortening the length would be more efficient. Are there any ways to shorten this?

```
def package1():
    try:
        #move to model name and click
        gui.moveTo(x=1016, y=701, duration=1.0)
        gui.click()
        print 'Navigating to Package'
        time.sleep(15)

        #move to update name and click
        gui.moveTo(x=661, y=526, duration=1.0)
        gui.click()
        print 'Navigating to Update version'
        time.sleep(15)

        #save setup file popup, move to save button
        gui.moveTo(x=1155, y=800, duration=1.0)
        gui.click()
        print 'Save setup popup'
        time.sleep(5)

        #navigate documents folder
        print 'Navigating to Documents'
        gui.moveTo(x=675, y=370, duration=1.5)
        gui.click()
        time.sleep(2)

        #navigate to date today folder
        print 'Navigating to Update folder'
        gui.moveTo(x=885, y=356, duration=1.5)
        gui.click(clicks=2)
        gui.moveTo(x=885, y=356, duration=1.5)
        gui.click(clicks=2)
        time.sleep(2)

        #navigate to which windows v folder and save to start downloading
        gui.moveTo(x=881, y=378, duration=1.0)
        gui.click()
        gui.moveTo(x=1315, y=738, duration=1.0)
        gui.click()
        print 'Downloading package...'
        time.sleep(240)
        print 'Package finished downloading, check for errors'
        gui.moveTo(x=1178, y=637, duration=1.0)
        gui.click()
        gui.moveTo(x=1260, y=798, duration=1.0)
        gui.click()
        gui.moveTo(x=618, y=393, duration=1.0)
        gui.click()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print 'Program stopped..'
```

Comment: You can post it here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

If you see a part of a code recurring, in most cases you can create a function.

Maybe sth like:

```py
def move_and_click(x,y,duration,sleep, name=""):
    gui.moveTo(x=x, y=y, duration=duration)
    gui.click()
    print 'Navigating to {}'.format(name)
    time.sleep(sleep)

def package1():
    try:
        move_and_click(10,12,1.0,15, "test")
        ...
```

If you really want to create a master function, you could read x and y as lists and move and click for each item in this list... (to ensure it also works for "navigate to date today folder")

Comment: yeah, now that you've mentioned that I noticed it too. some of the code is recurring. thanks a lot! i'll try to recreate the structure with functions.

Answer (score 2):

While Brizar's answer is quite good, you may want to this function accept series of move/click instructions. Such instructions should be passed as iterables of tuples (or namedtuples).

```
def move_and_click_2(instructions, sleep, name=None):
    for x,y,duration in instructions:
        gui.moveTo(x=x, y=y, duration=duration)
        gui.click()
    if name is not None:
        print 'Navigating to {}'.format(name)
    time.sleep(sleep)

def package1():
    try:
        move_and_click2([(10,12,1.0)],15, "test")
        move_and_click2([(30,20,1.0),(20,22,2.0)],15, "test2")
```